# how to implement Lazyload in Flutter ListView like whatsapp chat screen

Tags: flutter, pagination, lazy-loading, whatsapp, flutter-listview

I'm trying to understand how **WhatsApp chat screen** fetching old chats if we **scroll to top**.

similarly I wanted to do lazy load on reaching the top of the conversation. in my case assume 10,000 conversations(Obviously can't fetch all 10k items in one shot) in a chat where stored in local.

Initially i'm fetching latest 250 records and auto scrolled to last item in `ListView.Builder()`.

have no clue how the fetch remaining conversations on the top of the List.

Please help me to implement Lazy load here, looking forward for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

ListView.builder automatically have this Lazy load feature. I am not sure whether at the time of this question posting, flutter provides this feature or not. But, now in latest Flutter its already there.